# Playback controls in frameless VLC? (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, gui

I use VLC in frameless mode (no window decorations), but I would like it to show the playback controls when I hover over it with the mouse.

Is there a way to enable this function?

Bonus question: when I start a video it usually opens in a window that fills the entire screen (not full screen), is there a way to set VLC to open files in a more compact window?

Answer (score 2):

*Edit* - sorry, this is a bit 'stream of consciousness' with some guesswork, but go with the flow & see where you get ;)

---

Still hunting for why you don't see controls in fullscreen, but in the meantime here's your bonus...

Note: VLC must always be quit & relaunched to show changes.

Prefs > Show All > Interface > Main Interfaces > macosx > Resize interface to the native video size ... uncheck.
This will keep the initial playback in the same size window as your Playlist.

[image]

tbh, I'm not sure what you mean by 'frameless', but I'm assuming for some reason you're not using the regular Fullscreen toggle, F.
Maybe that's all it is, use VLC's fullscreen, F, not the macOS fullscreen [which in VLC if you click the green dot is the old 'fill the window as far as it will' rather than true fullscreen]

Ah - I just discovered ... basic prefs > Video > Use native Fullscreen - switch that off unless you want your second monitor to go black

Btw, the rather glaringly obvious "Show fullscreen controller" in my image appears to do absolutely nothing. I get the fullscreen controls if I move the mouse, whichever way that is set.

OK, my best guess is you're running with Window Decorations off.. which is horrible, it floats the video out on its own with no apparent method of control.
Try this instead for all of the first 2 blocks of that pref pane...

[image]

That will make it playback inside the same window as your Playlist, will keep the regular controls underneath, then when you go to fullscreen, will only show them when you move the mouse. It will also still let you use a second monitor whilst full screening in the other.

---

*Late edit* - I eventually figured it out - when you're in Frameless [Window Decorations off] then your controls are still at the bottom of the playlist window.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thanks for the answer! I do see the controls in full screen but I don't see the controls in [Window Decorations off] windowed VLC.

I would like them to show when I hover over with the mouse, something like you see in quicktime where every control disappears in windowed mode.

Comment: Hi - yeah, sorry for the somewhat confused answer. I was researching as I went along. I don't think it's possible with that 'frameless' mode. I poked at every likely control & several unlikely ones. The playback controls stay on the playlist window in that mode.

Comment: That's a bummer! Not even with some plugin?

But thanks anyways for the answer, especially to the bonus question, they weren't confusing at all.

Comment: I wouldn't know about plugins, I've never investigated - I tend to simply use it fullscreen piped out to a big TV, so I'm just watching not trying to work at the same time.